# understanding a basic objC thing

Tags: objective-c

i am trying to understand something.
in class A , i am creating an instance of classB , which there -in B , there is a timer, that ALWAYS  repeat, and he fire a recording and playing system-forever.

in class A, i create the instance of B with :

```
recordMachine *recMinst=[[recordMachine alloc]init];
[recMinst startMachine];
[recMinst release];
```

the thing is, that in classB there are instance variables in the interface, such as the player,recorder pointers, and other integers.

the question is, how this classB continue to work, after i release the instance in A ??
**doesnt A create a place in memory to store all the B instance variables and when i release it -they disappear ?**

Comment: i dont think i am. how can i be sure ?

Comment: If you would use ARC the compiler would complain at [recMachine release]. So if it builds you're not using ARC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> doesnt A create a place in memory to store all the B instance
>   variables and when i release it -they disappear ?

Yes and no, release does not work like C++ delete for example, it does not delete the object and clean its memory, but only decrease its reference count. If another object is holding onto it, then it won't get deallocated until that other object has also called release on it.

> the question is, how this classB continue to work, after i release the
>   instance in A ??

The only explanation as to why B continues to work is because some other object is holding onto it.

You mention class B uses a timer (most likely an NSTimer) which you would have passed your B instance to. Thus NSTimer is keeping a reference to your B object and preventing it from getting destroyed.

Check the ref count on your instance to be sure.

[NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) says "The target object is retained by the timer and released when the timer is invalidated."

Comment: thanks. i was thinking that this is the issue.  so anything in that class that has a timer, is retain till validate ?  so when i release A its useless ? i dont have to release it ?

Comment: The doc says the time will hold onto the object until it is invalidated, so all you need to do is invalidate the time in your destructor method. So call [myTime invalidate] and your B will get destroyed.

Comment: i do that. but in A i still have allocated object without a release?

Comment: You still need to release your object in A once you are done with it. If that still doesn't destroy the object B, then you have some other objects holding up on it. use Instruments's Zombies template in that case to figure out what's happening.

Comment: ok its working great thanks. so i can understand that i have to destory it in A also because even if the timer in B destroy it , A still hold it, and must release it also ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the B instance until its end, you must retain it in A object until the end of your A instance.
In your case the retain count of B is 0 after you release it, so it is deallocated.

If you want to keep it, you must retain it somewhere. I suggest you to retain it and release it in dealloc method of A

Comment: i didnt get you, i dont think thats what i have asked. my question was, how is that i RELEASE B instance, and it continue to work anyway? doesnt after release it, all its instances are gone ?

Comment: Ok, sorry. If B is still working, someone is retaining it OR it is created in autorelease, so it will be released where the autorelease-pool will be activated.
If you want to try it, enable NSZombie from the schemas and check if, after your release, your B variable is a Zombie.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not releasing B's ivars manually in `-dealloc` they are  still in memory.